# R - function return only first set of passed parameter

Tags: r

I am running into a strange problem in R.

In the attached script, I have 2  dataframe containing same data just in reversed order (data_asc, data_desc). Then I apply a same function (fnDoIt) with same parameters to both dataframes to create new column in each (cost).

The function split the strings by "|" then create a dataframe and return the "cost" element of the dataframe. The parameter_desc contain the parameter names separated by "|" while the parameter_value contain parameter values separated by "|" in same order.

However, when I run the script, it returns different values depend on what order my dataframe is. It seems to return the result of the first set of parameter.

What I expect to see is:

- A-----price|cost--------------10|7----------7
- B-----price|cost|tax_rate-----12|6|0.10-----6

But what i get (depend on the order of data frame) are either:

- A-----price|cost--------------10|7----------7
- B-----price|cost|tax_rate-----12|6|0.10-----7

or

- B-----price|cost|tax_rate-----12|6|0.10-----6
- A-----price|cost--------------10|7----------6

I am not sure how to get around this … really appreciate any help or insight from you guys

Thanks

```
stringsAsFactors=FALSE

fnDoIt = function(model
              , parameter_desc
              , parameter_value) {
  #process parameters
  #split string, then unlist
  parameter_desc = unlist(strsplit(parameter_desc
                                   , split = '|'
                                   , fixed = TRUE))

  #split string, then unlist, then convert to number
  parameter_value = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(parameter_value
                                               , split = '|'
                                               , fixed = TRUE)))

  #build dataframe for parameters
  parameter = as.data.frame(t(parameter_value)) #transpose vector to horizontal
  names(parameter) = parameter_desc #rename columns

  fnDoIt = parameter$cost 
}

data = data.frame(model = c('A','B')
                  , parameter_desc = c('price|cost','price|cost|tax_rate')
                  , parameter_value = c('10|7','12|6|0.10'))

data_asc = data
data_desc = data[order(data$model, decreasing = TRUE),]

data_asc$cost = fnDoIt(data_asc$model
                       , data_asc$parameter_desc
                       , data_asc$parameter_value)

data_desc$cost = fnDoIt(data_desc$model
                        , data_desc$parameter_desc
                        , data_desc$parameter_value)
```

**UPDATED**:

```
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
fnDoIt = function(model
                  , production
                  , parameter_desc
                  , parameter_value) {

  #process parameters
  #split string, then unlist
  parameter_desc = unlist(strsplit(parameter_desc
                                   , split = '|'
                                   , fixed = TRUE))

  #split string, then unlist, then convert to number
  parameter_value = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(parameter_value
                                               , split = '|'
                                               , fixed = TRUE)))

  if (model == 'A') {
    temp = parameter_value[parameter_desc == 'cost']
  } else if (model == 'B') {
    temp = parameter_value[parameter_desc == 'tax_rate']
  }

  fnDoIt = temp * production
}

data = data.frame(model = c('A','B','B')
                  , production = c(100,185,210)
                  , parameter_desc = c('price|cost','price|cost|tax_rate','price|cost|tax_rate')
                  , parameter_value = c('10|7','14|9|0.20','12|6|0.10'))

data$cost = ifelse(data$model == 'A'
                       , fnDoIt('A'
                                , data$production
                                , data$parameter_desc
                                , data$parameter_value)
                       , fnDoIt('B'
                                , data$production
                                , data$parameter_desc
                                , data$parameter_value))
```

I received the error:

> In temp * production: longer object length is not a multiple of
>   shorter object length

Comment: I don't know for others, but I get `Error in strsplit(parameter_desc, split = "|", fixed = TRUE) : 
  non-character argument
` running your example.

Comment: Based on Pascal's comments, I think you need `strsplit(as.character(parameter_desc),..` as `strsplit` takes only `character` class or change the `class` of 'parameter_desc` to `character` by using `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` in the `data` creation step.

Comment: There seems to be multiple problems, for one your function is not returning anything. In `R` functions returns the value of the last expression evaluated or using `return(something)` . Additionally I think you are incorrectly assigning names of `parameter`. You should probably rephrase the question to show what is your expected output

Comment: Thank you, guys. But when i ran this in R studio, it works just fine. I am new to R so appreciate any help i can get.

I forgot to add `stringsAsFactors=FALSE` (added to original post)

Comment: @jMathew, can you please elaborate on what what i incorrectly assigned? I am a bit confused. Rephrased the original question a little bit

Comment: @TaiNguyen : I hope my answer clears your doubt

Comment: Still same error. Your working example doesn't work.

Comment: @Pascal, I'm not quite sure why. It seems to work for me when I ran that whole script in R Studio :(

Comment: Do you run it in a clean environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for,

```
fnGetCost <- function(df){
  apply(df, 1, 
    function(r){
      parms <- unlist(strsplit(r[2], split="\\|")) 
      costIX <- which(parms == "cost")
      as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(r[3], split="\\|"))[costIX])
    })
}

data_asc$cost = fnGetCost(data_asc)

data_desc$cost = fnGetCost(data_desc)
```

Your original solution is considering all the rows at once. Check the output of

```
unlist(strsplit(as.character(data_asc$parameter_desc)
            , split = '|'
            , fixed = TRUE))
```

So finally you have multiple columns with column names `cost` while you are returning only one of them. If you really want to use your function replace the last three line with

```
parameter_value[parameter_desc == "cost"]
```

Additionally note that the original function throws an error as the columns of data are coerced to `factor`

Comment: Hi @jMathew, thank you for the suggestion. That last line work like a charm! 

I was able to run through the script using apply function instead of the mentioned approach. However, it is much slower on larger set (though it yield the right result). I started playing around with vectors to see if performance can be improved...and run into this particular problem

May I ask if you can explain "Your original solution is considering all the rows at once"? I'm a bit confused on how R deal with element of vector..

Again, really appreciate your help, Mathew!

Comment: In your original solution, the first `strsplit` will return a list of lists. The outer list iterates over each element of `parameter_desc` (i.e. each row) while the inner list contains split description for each row. Now when you apply `unlist`, the two level list is flattened to a vector, hence you will loose the row information. Is this clearer?

Comment: Ah, I see. it makes more sense now.

when I extended the above script to return "length(parameter_value[parameter_desc == 'cost']", it returns 2 ... should it be 1?

How do I stop the outer list from iterating over each element (row)? sound like, basically, i just need to get the inner list.

Comment: Why would you want to stop it from iterating over each element? And I think the length should be 2 as the number of rows in your data is 2

Comment: Hi @jMathew, basically, i just need a temporary data frame inside the fnDoIt so i can easily refer to its elements by name. Having the outer list expand with every iteration can make it hard to refer to the current row being split... Sorry for the silly question, but R is quite new to me..

Comment: Hey, I still don't get you, maybe you should start a fresh question explaining exactly whats in your mind?

Comment: Hi @jMathew,
i've updated the original script to show what I'm trying to achieve. I have 2 models (possibly more in the full set) with some common parameter and some unique parameters to each model.

the data set is in format like "data" with "production" is the common parameter and "cost" / "tax_rate" are unique to each case.

depend on the model, i would like the function to pick a unique and a common parameters to calculate the output. when i run the updated script, it returns a warning suggesting they are different size.

Comment: This is not the most elegant solution, but try `unsplit(lapply(split(data, data$model), function(ele) fnDoIt(ele$model, ele$production, ele$parameter_desc, ele$parameter_value)), data$model)` Do start a new question if this doesn't fit